# How to set time limit for file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I use SIMPLE HTML DOM for parsing. Some pages take a very long time when i try to get contents.
I need to set limit (for example 10 sec) -> go to the next page.
Please without socket!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the HTTP [context option](http://de.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

So the code would look like

```
$options = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
    'timeout' => 10 //10 seconds
    )
));
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/', false, $options);
```